# command line list files in subfolders but not current folder

Tags: batch, batch-file, directory-listing

I have a batch file that gives me a directory listing of all files in current and subfolders. I would like to change this to list all files that are in subfolders but **NOT** the current folder. Currently I am using this command below which successfully works to list all the files in the current folder AND subfolders.

```
cd "c:\temp"
dir  /s/b *.doc>c:\temp\mylist.txt
```

This produces results as follows:

```
c:\temp\test8.doc
c:\temp\test9 (2).doc
c:\temp\test9.doc
c:\temp\012015\blah_012340.doc
c:\temp\032016\blah_124756.doc
c:\temp\042016\blah_125230.doc
c:\temp\052016\blah_052647.doc
```

I would like my results to not show what is directly in c:\temp, so my desired results would be:

```
c:\temp\012015\blah_012340.doc
c:\temp\032016\blah_124756.doc
c:\temp\042016\blah_125230.doc
c:\temp\052016\blah_052647.doc
```

Comment: Why don't you use `tree /f` for better visual quality?

Comment: I'm not an expert on PowerShell but I think you can do it easily on PowerShell using `-include` and `-exclude` switches of `dir` (alias).

Comment: I don't think tree wil work as I need the list dumped into a list, which I then use for my next function in the batch file.  Powershell may work but I don't know powershell either. I guess I can try and find some examples that might work and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
for /f "delims=" %5  in ('dir /a:d /b') do dir /b /s  "%5"
```

Here's the breakdown for this one liner.

`for /f` is used to loop a list of items.

`"delims="` sets the delimiters to none so it treats each line as a single phrase. By default spaces will be treated as a delimiter.

`%5` is the variable.

`in ('dir /a:d /b')` this gets the list of directories of the target folder.

`do dir /b /s  "%5"` here you define your action `do` followed by the command and then the variable `%5` as an argument.

Please note that when you run this from a batch file you must use `%%5`

`for /f "delims=" %%5  in ('dir /a:d /b') do dir /b /s  "%%5"`

Hope this helps.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like this will work as soon as I figure out what I am messing up. I am not too sure if the `%5` was something I am supposed to modify so I left as is. I added the code you listed to my batch. 

The results that it outputted did exclude the files that were in the "root" directory that I am searching. However it only listed one sub-directory, and in this test there were 3 sub-directories.

As it stands right now the pertinent part of my script is reading as follows:

    cd "c:\temp"
    for /f "delims=" %%5  in ('dir /a:d /b') do dir /b /s  "%%5">%list%

Comment: Since it treats as different commands so you have to use `>>`. in your case  `for /f "delims=" %%5 in ('dir /a:d /b') do dir /b /s "%%5">>%list%`